# Insert list inside pandas dataframe column names

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I initiate like this:

```
df = pd.DatFrame(columns=('col_A', 'col_B', 'col_C', 'col_D'))
```

I want to insert a list of column names in this dataframe, but this does not work:

```
list_col_names = ['aa', 'bb']
df = pd.DatFrame(columns=('col_A', 'col_B', list_col_names, 'col_C', 'col_D'))
```

I get this error: `*** TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

How do I fix it? I want all the items in list_col_names to become column names in the pandas dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are effectively passing in `('col_A', 'col_B', ['aa', 'bb'], 'col_C', 'col_D')` as an argument; so for example, try `df = pd.DataFrame(columns =
 ['col_A', 'col_B'] + list_col_names + ['col_C', 'col_D'])` instead.

You got an error because pandas tried to create a single column from a list `['aa', 'bb']`, which doesn't work.